# How would be this scientific notation regular expression in C#?

Tags: c#, regex

I'm using this regular expression for a scientific notation and setting to REGEX class in C#.

```
[-+]?[0-9]*\.?[0-9]+([eE][-+]?[0-9]+)?
```

But it's not really working.

Comment: what do you want it to match?

Comment: A scientific notation, like -4.70e+9, -.2E-4, 0.2e4

Comment: This works for me in expresso

Comment: Well, I'm putting that in C# but, it tells me that \. is a escape secuence, and I don't know how can I fix that.

Comment: either escape the slash like this: `\\.` or use a verbatim string literal `@"[-+]?[0-9]*\.?[0-9]+([eE][-+]?[0-9]+)?"`

Comment: but now, is there another problem.. I can only input letters and +- in the textbox, but not numbers (maybe is there something wrong in the regexp)

Answer (score 5):

An alternative that's likely easier:

```
double.TryParse(stringInput, out doubleOutput);
```

[Double.TryParse](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/994c0zb1.aspx) handles scientific notation by default.

Comment: +1.             string input = "0.2e";
            double output;
            Console.WriteLine(double.TryParse(input, out output)? "Valid": "Invalid");

Answer (score 2):

What's not working about it?

One potential problem I see is that you're allowing leading 0s, and also trailing 0s in the decimal. Not sure if you want either, both, or neither. You should also make the decimal portion optional, but dependent on the existence of the decimal point. Here's what I'd recommend:

```
[-+]?(0?|[1-9][0-9]*)(\.[0-9]*[1-9])?([eE][-+]?(0|[1-9][0-9]*))?
```

That will match:

```
0
0.1
0.01
1
1.1
1.01
10
10.1
10.01
1e1
1
1e0
1E1
1e10
```

It won't match:

```
.
01
1.0
1.10
1e01
```